# Simulate GMail WebVIew

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

I'm trying to simulate something GMail for Android does when opening emails. I guess email viewer is using WebView, however it's quite clever:

- It displays email Sender, Photo and a few buttons in a blue panel on top
- Recipients and other Headers display in a collapsed panel you can expand
- Scrolling up gradually hides all the added information except for the blue panel (magic?)

If they do that using CSS I'm wondering how is it possible at all. Mixing CSS in the same html is not possible. Zooming the page leaves default controls untouched etc.

Possible to replicate?

Comment: Use `uiautomatorviewer` to see what widgets make up the Gmail UI.

Comment: I'd be highly shocked if gmail for android is a webview-  its almost certainly a native app written in Java.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for suggestion, great tool. Looks like they're drawing over WebView in a RelativeLayout, not trivial to replicate :(

Comment: That's precisely why I didn't want to try to give an answer. :-) I think Kiril Grouchnikov has some blog posts about similar simultaneous-scrolling techniques used by the Play Store client, though I am uncertain if he provided all of the details.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm getting some results by using ScrollView, embedding my custom View for cool header and WebView in it i.e. (ScrollView (LinearLayout (CustomView, WebView))) still quite shaky though. I'll post it here once it works ;)